# get item price before applying shopping cart price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules

i m trying to display price in subtotal before shopping cart price rule aaplied.but it always give nothing when print my code.i m use below code to display price in cart.

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($_item->getProduct(),$_item->getProduct()->getPrice());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get direct price as below. Above function might give you price after catalog rule applied on it.

```
  <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice(); ?>
```

Comment: sorry but it gives 4408.90 not 4326.75